# Changing the architecture of a dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using a certain analysis tool that can directly replace the `col_F` by using an easier version of SQL.

The content of the replacement has to be coded.

| col_A | col_B | col_C | col_D | col_E | col_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 0001 | Design | Useable | Not Applicable | Not Applicable |
| 1111 | 0002 | NULL | NULL | Without | Straight |

For example in the table, I want the 'Not Applicable' in `col_F` to be changed by the 'Straight' of the column below.

More precisely, I want to replace the 'Not Applicable' in `col_F` by the row that has : (the same col_A) + (the col_b + 1) + (the col_F that has 1 of two possible answers).

There are 10 of thousands of rows but this is just an example.

This code is very wrong but it is just to understand what I try to do.

```
CASE

 WHEN "col_F" = 'Not Applicable' THEN
    (
    "col_F"  WHEN
    "col_F" IN ('Straight', 'Not Straight')
    AND "col_a" = "col_a"
    AND CAST ("col_b" AS INTEGER) = CAST ("col_b" AS INTEGER) + 1
    )
 ELSE "col_F" 

END;
```

There is an error because it tells me to put a THEN after the second WHEN, which makes sens. The problem is that I can not use regular SQL and can only do it with CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END.

Someone got an idea on how to do it?

I tried to solve the problem with the code but because I can not use regular sql I have to find a way only with CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END;

Comment: To access values from rows "below", there is the need for window functions such as `lead`.  Here you need to provide a ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with a join

```sql
WITH
  tbl AS (
  SELECT
    1111 AS col_a,
    0001 AS col_B,
    "Design" col_C,
    "Useable" AS col_d,
    "Not Applicable" AS col_E,
    "Not Applicable" AS col_f
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111,0002, NULL, NULL,  "Without", "Straight" 
  ),
  helper AS (
  SELECT
    col_b-1 AS col_B,
    col_a,
    ANY_VALUE(col_f) AS col_f_replace
  FROM tbl
  WHERE  col_F IN ('Straight',  'Not Straight')
  GROUP BY  1, 2
  )
SELECT
  *,
IF(col_f_replace IS NOT NULL  AND col_f="Not Applicable",col_f_replace,col_f)
FROM  tbl
LEFT JOIN  helper
USING  (col_a, col_b)
```

If the `col_b` is countinous increasing, a solution with a window function

```
lead(col_f) over (partition by col_a order by col_b)
```

is possible without the `helper` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AND in CASE Statements so something like this

```
CASE
  WHEN "col_F" = 'Not Applicable'
    AND "col_F" IN ('Straight', 'Not Straight')
    AND "col_a" = "col_a"
    AND CAST ("col_b" AS INTEGER) = CAST ("col_b" AS INTEGER) + 1
  THEN "col_E"
  ELSE "col_F" 
END
```

Comment: the first two conditions are mutually exclusive so the entire case will never be true

Comment: @kurt -- yes, I know the logic of the original question did not make sense.  It seems clear the OP did not know how to use AND in a case statement.